# NodeJS Firebase create custom Token for android app

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a NodeJS server for authentication. I use Firebase for create custom token to send notification to androidApp. But when i create a new user I have this error:

Error: Uncaught error: error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long

I use the same code of [Firebase setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup) and for create custom token I use this: `var customToken = firebase.auth().createCustomToken(uid);` where uid is the email of the user that go to register.
I obtain this mail by hapiJS and mongodb.
There is anyone help me?

Or if anyone have idea for send notification by nodes server without token it is god for my case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be the `uid`. It is **not** the *email* of the user, but a unique identifier that looks like `88h5s9fafVN6P4AaENOZZ1Aso3h7` and is associated with the user.

You can get the `uid` once the user is successfully logged in or by going to the firebase auth section on the console and looking for `User UID`.